# Detecting string similarity using Levenshtein distance (is SLOW)

Tags: c#, .net, sql, string-comparison

The query returns 21 million records

They way I loop through this table takes forever. What other solutions are there?

```
SqlDataReader rd = DbInfo.DataRdr(Conn,
 "SELECT a.NAME AS ANAME, b.NAME AS BNAME, a.ID as AID, b.ID AS BUD " +
 "FROM myTable a JOIN myTable b ON a.NUM = b.NUM AND a.ID <> b.ID");

while (rd.Read())
{
   if (rd["ANAME"].ToString().LevenshteinDistance(rd["BNAME"].ToString()) <= 10)
   {

        Logging.Write(...);

   }
}



    public static int LevenshteinDistance(this string s, string t)
    {
        if (s == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
        if (t == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("t");
        int n = s.Length;
        int m = t.Length;
        int[,] d = new int[n+1,m+1];

        if (n == 0 || m == 0)
            return Math.Max(m, n);

        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            d[i, 0] = i;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            d[0, i] = i;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                int cost = (t[j] == s[i]) ? 0 : 1;

                d[i + 1, j + 1] = Math.Min(Math.Min(d[i, j + 1] + 1, d[i + 1, j] + 1), d[i, j] + cost);
            }
        }

        return d[n, m];
    }
```

Comment: SELECT * is bad to start with. Any chance you can improve the query?

Comment: can we see the code for the LevenshteinDistance function?

Comment: @John haha... he presumably means that one of those should be a "j".

Comment: which i ? :P   Ok I fixed that

Comment: Not going to be faster, but it is worth noting that this is possible in pure SQL: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=51540&whichpage=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start by using the following as your query instead, depending on how often the `NUM` columns are actually equal:

```
SELECT a.NAME AS ANAME, b.NAME AS BNAME, other things
FROM myTable a
JOIN myTable b
ON a.NUM = b.NUM
AND a.id < b.id
```

Then your SQL query will give you pairs of rows with matching `NUM`s that you can call `LevenshteinDistance` on. Something like:

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Load(DbInfo.DataRdr(Conn, "[the query I wrote above]"));

for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   if (dt1.Rows[i]["ANAME"].ToString().LevenshteinDistance(dt1.Rows[i]["BNAME"].ToString()) <= 10)
   {
     Logging.Write(...[modify the query so it returns the things you want to log]...);
   }
}
```

Comment: your query returns more than 7 million records, my table has 130000 records

Comment: The reason your original code took a long time to execute is that you were doing a query that returned 130000 records, then executing your Levenshtein function 130000*130000 = 16.9 **billion** times. 7 million is a marked improvement (my query returns all the pairs of records to compare)!

Comment: As another answer said, write LevenshteinDistance better so that it doesn't go to so much trouble. If you only ever care about whether the distance is greater than 10, you can stop distance calculations very early in a large number of cases.

Comment: count returns 21 million rows

Comment: how can I optimize the Lev method

Comment: hmm .Net throws System.OutOfMemory exception on the query

Comment: Are you `SELECT`ing `*`? You can probably reduce the size of the query results by selecting less data. Or you can do it in small chunks if you really want, so run the query with `AND a.id < 100000` at first, then do the next 100000, and so on (but make sure you only put the restriction on one of `a.id` and `b.id`!).

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing `dt1.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString()` with `dt1.Rows[j]["Name"].ToString()` even when `i == j`.

Try looping `0 <= i < dt1.Rows.Count - 1` and `i + 1 <= j < dt1.Rows.Count`.

Also, you're logging only if `dt1.Rows[i]["NUM"].ToString() == dt1.Rows[i]["NUM"].ToString()`, which is probably a faster check. There's no point in doing Levenshtein if that's false.

EDIT: @John is right about the `dt1.Rows[i]["NUM"].ToString() == dt1.Rows[i]["NUM"].ToString()` (both `i`?).

Answer (score 1):

**Optimizations:**

1) Take a look at your data. Maybe you can do some checks to sort out invalid pairs faster. If the lenght of `Name` varies over more than 10 you can check if the difference between `s.Lenght` and `t.Length` is greater 10 and return a high distance right away (maybe int.MaxValue or just 100). There is no point in calculating the distance if it`s clearly out of scope anyway.

2) Look for small optimizations. Looping twice over 150k rows means 22.5 billion iterations. Small changes may have a great effect.  You may try to cache to row objects and remove the `ToString()` by usign the `Equals()` method. I think this would be faster than accessing the i-th element of your datatable 150000 times.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   var outerRow = dt1.Rows[i];
   for (int j = 0; i + 1 < dt1.Rows.Count; j++)
   {
     var innerRow = dt1.Rows[j];
     if (Equals(outerRow["NUM"] == innerRow["NUM"]))
     {
        if (outerRow["Name"].ToString().LevenshteinDistance(innerRow.ToString()) <= 10)
        {
           Logging.Write(...);
        }
     }
  }
```

3) Try to reduce/split the datasets. Execute a query to get all possible values of `NUM` `select distinct NUM from myTable`. Then for each `NUM` in your result do your original query but using a where condition and select only the name: `SELECT name from myTable where NUM = currentNum`.

This way you don`t have to compare the NUM row and you don`t select odd data. Your code can be optimized to do just the levenshtein distance but using the optimizations stated in 1+2.

4) Try a different approach like fulltext search.

I just hat to solve a similar problem, finding matches in a 1.2 million rows table. I used [lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) which provides me realtime results when searching over one or more properties of my rows.

They do levenshtein too, but Maybe its faster than your implementation ;) MSSQL Server supports fulltext search, too.

Comment: my current problme is the System.OutOfMemoryexception error which gets thrown when I run the Chris Cunningham query

Comment: I made some changes to the code, please see the question code above. These changes solved the memory exception error but again it's slow.

Comment: Looks like this is the fastest it can get, I removed the LevenShtein method and it didn't effect the speed that much.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest improvement you can make is to reduce the solution space being considered. Since you want a max distance of 10, any strings that differ by length more than 10 cannot possibly qualify:

```
SELECT a.NAME AS ANAME, b.NAME AS BNAME, a.ID as AID, b.ID AS BUD 
 FROM myTable a JOIN myTable b ON a.NUM = b.NUM AND a.ID < b.ID
 WHERE length(a.NAME) - length(b.NAME) BETWEEN -10 AND 10;
```

Next, profile your code and see where are the hot spots. A good entry article: [Find Application Bottlenecks with Visual Studio Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx).

And have a look at [Optimizing the Levenshtein Algorithm in C#](http://sadgeeksinsnow.blogspot.com/2010/10/optimizing-levenshtein-algorithm-in-c.html).

*Edit*

Also Chris noticed that since `levenshtein(a,b) == levenshtein(b,a)` you need only select on the join a.ID < b.ID, since the matrix is symmetrical. This will halve your problem right off the bat.

Answer (score 0):

After doing the other optimizations mentioned in this thread, you can move the Levenshtein computation to the server and only SELECT the rows that matches your Edit distance criteria. I needed this functionality in a project, so I made a library out of it, [here](https://bitbucket.org/vgrit/clrsquirrel). The edit distance method used in the lib only requires n * 2 memory instead of n * m.

For instance, even when on the server, you only want to do the EditDistance computation when the difference in string length is < 10, so check for that first. 
Something like

```
SELECT a.NAME as NameA, b.NAME as NameB
FROM table a
JOIN table b ON a.NUM = b.NUM
WHERE a.Id < b.Id
AND length(a.NAME) - length(b.NAME) BETWEEN -10 AND 10 OR
    EditDistance(a.Name, b.Name) < 10
```